# C pointer arithmetic different for char * and int *

Tags: c, pointers

Could someone explain why I can move through the memory locations for the char * but not for the int * using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
int *  a = malloc(48);  
char * s = malloc(27);

for (int i = 0;i<26;i++) s[i] = i+65;

int intSize = sizeof(int);
printf("%d\n",intSize); 

for(int i = 0;i<12;i++){
    a[i] = i;
    printf("%d %d %c\n",*(a+i*intSize),a[i],*(s+i));
}


return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Because performing `a+i` will increment the address by `i*sizeof(int)` automatically. And you are duplicating this functionality manually, making it invalid.

Comment: C is smart enough to increment a pointer by the size of the date type that it points to. So if you have `int *p`, then `p + 1` points to *the next `int`* not the next byte.

Comment: thank you, that's right on the money

Comment: Note: rather than assume the size of an `int` is 4, use `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof *a`.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is already related to the size of what the pointer points at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you declare a variable e.g.

```
int* a;
char* b;
```

all offsets are in the end calculated as byte offsets, the size of the offset depends on the type.

so `a + 1` is in reality `a + sizeof(int)` and `b + 1` is in reality `b + sizeof(char)`

the compiler handles this, it makes it easier to read the code otherwise you would always have to calculate how many bytes a type has when looping through an array and such

Answer (score 2):

`char *` has a one byte resolution. `int *` has (usually) a 4 byte resolution. Increment and decrement for a pointer of any type T go by `sizeof(T)`. That's what makes pointer arithmetic usable.

Comment: `int *` has a `sizeof int` "resolution".    There are plenty of real world implementations where `sizeof int` is not `4`.

Comment: Thus the "(usually)".

Comment: Just because it is "usual" for you, does not mean it is usual for everyone.

Comment: Why not generalize the answer, especially if it doesn't require any significant effort?

Comment: What part of "Increment and decrement for a pointer of any type T go by sizeof(T)." is not generalized?

Comment: The answer has the other part, which is triggering the debate above.

Comment: @RobK, "Increment and decrement for a pointer of any type T go by sizeof(T)" is reasonably general, but wrong.  It pretty much duplicates much the OP's underlying problem.  C pointer arithmetic takes account of the size of the pointed-to type for you.

Comment: It's not remotely wrong. For all `T * p = &t; p++;` the value of `p` will be `sizeof(T)` greater after the increment.

Comment: I think @JohnBollinger meant that instead of " pointer of any type T" it should be "pointer **to** any type T".

Comment: @Rob K - unless `t` is an expression that references an element of an array, your example `T * p = &t; p++;` gives undefined behaviour.   If it is well defined, then `p - &t` will give the value of `1`, not `sizeof T`.