# Searching that works for any type of data(both built-in or user defined data)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, character, user-defined-types

I am trying to understand the ff searching algorithm, (that tries to find the index of the element being searched). However, I don't know how it can work with any type of data type. So, the ff questions still remain

1. inside the code, it says we can use char pointer since char is only one byte. However, once we made it a char pointer, doesn't it become 8 bytes instead of one byte? also even if it becomes, one byte, how does it help us deal with any type of data(as it claims to do so inside the code)?
2. since the whole thing claims, it can work for any type of data, does this **work for user-defined data(like structs)?** if so, I would appreciate an explanation on how to do so.(i.e. how can we make this work for both  **int a[] ={7,3,5,7,8,90} and struct student {char *name, int score, int id}**
   struct student stude_array [] ={{"Rebeka",92,10},{"Alext",97,11},{"james",90,12}}** data types and search for specific element in each arrays? thank you for your help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// A compare function that is used for searching an integer
// array
bool compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
return ( *(int*)a == *(int*)b );
}

// General purpose search() function that can be used
// for searching an element *x in an array arr[] of
// arr_size. Note that void pointers are used so that
// the function can be called by passing a pointer of
// any type. ele_size is size of an array element
int search(void *arr, int arr_size, int ele_size, void *x,
        bool compare (const void * , const void *))
{
    // Since char takes one byte, we can use char pointer
    // for any type/ To get pointer arithmetic correct,
    // we need to multiply index with size of an array
    // element ele_size
    char *ptr = (char *)arr;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
        if (compare(ptr + i*ele_size, x))
        return i;

    // If element not found
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 5, 7, 90, 70};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int x = 7;
    printf ("Returned index is %d ", search(arr, n,
                            sizeof(int), &x, compare));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `ele_size` is passed to the function. Using a `char *` allows the pointer math `ptr + i * ele_size` to work for any size object.

Comment: how would using int *  differ from using character pointer?

Comment: You need to understand how pointer math works. `somepointer + x` moves the pointer `sompointer + x * sizeof(somepointer's data type)` bytes. If you used `int *ptr = (int *)arr;` then `ptr + i * ele_size` would move the pointer ahead `ptr + i * sizeof(int)` bytes, which is too many. (Note that `sizeof(char) == 1`).

Comment: I'm probably not explaining it well. Do a search for "C pointer math". See also: [C pointer arithmetic different for char \* and int \*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41772460)

Comment: While your comparison function works here, most functions that use a comparator expect it to return zero on equality, a negative value if the first value is less than the second, and a positive value if the first value is greater than the second.  This is what `strcmp()` does; it is what `bsearch()` and `qsort()` require.

Comment: @Solruhama You might read the [man page for `qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort).  It, too, accepts a "generic" array pointer and an explicit argument telling the actual size of each array element.  It, too, requires a pointer to a user-supplied comparison function.  And for this reason it can indeed sort any kind of user-defined data. [`bsearch`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch) works that way, too.  And these are the same techniques your `search` function uses.  (Your `search` is like `bsearch`, except that it doesn't require sorted input and so can't perform binary search.)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. inside the code, it says we can use char pointer since char is only one byte. However, once we made it a char pointer, doesn't it
>    become 8 bytes instead of one byte?

It's talking there about the pointer and pointer arithmetic, not about the pointed-to object.  No part of the pointed-to data is converted, and the size of a pointer (which is not necessarily 8 bytes) has nothing to do with it.

> also even if it becomes, one byte,
> how does it help us deal with any type of data(as it claims to do so
> inside the code)?

The key thing here is that pointer arithmetic, such as `ptr + i*ele_size`, operates in units the size of the pointed-to type.  If you want to perform such computations in one-byte units, then you need to do it with a pointer to a character type (or to an extension type of that size).

> 2. since the whole thing claims, it can work for any type of data, does this **work for user-defined data(like structs)**?

The `search()` function *can* work with any type of data.  Whether it *does* work depends on the user passing a pointer to a `compare` function that is appropriate to the particular type of data provided in that call.

> if so, I would
> appreciate an explanation on how to do so.(i.e. how can we make this
> work for both *int a[] ={7,3,5,7,8,90} and struct student {char name,
> int score, int id} struct student stude_array []
> ={{"Rebeka",92,10},{"Alext",97,11},{"james",90,12}}* data types and search for specific element in each arrays?

You already presented an example of how to use it for an array of `int`.  For the struct array, you must, again, provide an appropriate comparison function.  So,

```
bool compare_students(const void * a, const void * b) {
    const struct student *student_a = a;
    const struct student *student_b = b;

    // comparison details left as an exercise ...
}

// ...

void f(void) {
    struct student student_array[] = {{"Rebeka", 92, 10}, {"Alext", 97, 11},
            {"james", 90, 12}};
    struct student james = {"james", 90, 12};
    struct student john = {"John", 99, 17};

    int index = search(student_array, 3, sizeof(struct student), &james,
            compare_students);
    printf("james: %d\n", index);

    index = search(student_array, 3, sizeof(struct student), &john,
            compare_students);
    printf("john: %d\n", index);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed and clear explanation on this. and i understand what you did there, but i was asking if there is a way to just have one compare function that can be used in the search to search any type of data(user defined or built in) instead of customizing for each type of data like the compare function you wrote, that works only for struct data type?

Comment: @Solruhama, you say that as if I played some kind of trick.  I did not.  I interpreted the question in terms of the claims that you reported your text to have made about the code presented, which seems the most natural alternative.  Your text surely does not intend to claim that the *combination* of `search()` and `compare()` functions it presents will work for data of any type (else, get a better book).  It should in any case be clear from this answer that although `search()` is type-agnostic, the comparison function used with it must be type-specific.

Comment: again thanks for your answer, i really appreciate that. and my english is not good so sorry if there was a bad meaning in the comment. and back to my question, the compare function takes void pointers, which means it is type agnostic too. but i guess the compare function should be specific for the data type used even though the parameters used are type agnostic. correct me if i understood your comment wrong?